# find a specific element in nested XML File Spark scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I want to select a spaecific element : 
`select("File.columns.column._name")`

```
 |-- File: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _RowTag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Hive_Final_Table: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Hive_Final_column: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Hive_Table1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Hive_column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Path: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
```

I got this error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve 'File.columns.column[_name]' due to data type mismatch:
>   argument 2 requires integral type, however, '_name' is of string
>   type.;
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:65)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:334)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>           at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:108)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:118)

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) function to get the required column

> `explode(Column e)`
> Creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.

```
val df1 = df.select(explode($"File").as("File")).select($"File.columns").as("column")
```

First, explode gives you `column` field

```
val finalDF = df1.select(explode($"(column"))."column")).select($"column._name").as("_name")
```

Second explode gives you the `_name` column

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your schema you can do the following to select `_name` from the nested structs from `dataframe`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(col("File.columns.column")(0)(0)("_name").as("_name"))
```